# Getting the result of a Scala promise without a future

Tags: scala

Is there a way to directly get the value out of a successful promise?
Is it really necessary to connect a `future` to the promise, for that?

```
scala> import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent._

scala> val result = Promise[Int]
result: scala.concurrent.Promise[Int] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@2b5fa85f

scala> result success 3
res0: result.type = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@2b5fa85f

scala> result
res1: scala.concurrent.Promise[Int] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@2b5fa85f

scala> result.isCompleted
res4: Boolean = true

scala> result.value
<console>:12: error: value value is not a member of scala.concurrent.Promise[Int]
              result.value
                     ^

scala> result.future.value.get.get
res6: Int = 3
```

I am considering using a promise for thread-safe "assign once" semantics. The promise object looks lean enough in the scala.concurrent source, and as far as I understand it is thread safe. I'd rather however, avoid adding another object (a future). I could not find a getter for the success value of a promise.

Comment: Nope, by design of promise.

Comment: Maybe neater: `Await.result(p.future, Duration.Zero)`

Comment: @BenReich I believe that's not neater just rather different assumptions in practice. Await.result waits for the promise while .value assumes it has already succeeded. Different use cases.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### tl; dr

```
p.future == p
```

so don't worry about the extra allocation.

---

#### discussion

`Promise` and `Future` are complimentary. The former represents the write (once) side of the computation, while the latter is the read side.

So, in order to read a value from a `Promise` you will always need to do it via a `Future`.

On the other hand, it's worth noting that despite the abstract design, the implementation is quite efficient and `Promise` and `Future` are not separate entities. Here's the implementation of the `future` of `Promise`

```
private[concurrent] trait Promise[T] extends scala.concurrent.Promise[T] with scala.concurrent.Future[T] {
  def future: this.type = this
}
```

So, you can see that `p.future` is actuall the same as `p`, and it simply gets a different semantic.

Bottom line, you can access `future` from promise and you won't be paying any additional cost in terms of instance allocations.

Also, you can make the syntax nicer if you wish

```
scala> implicit class DirectAccessPromise[A](val p: Promise[A]) extends AnyVal {
     |   def get = p.future.value.get.get
     | }
defined class DirectAccessPromise

scala> val p = Promise.successful(42)
res0: scala.concurrent.Promise[Int] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$KeptPromise@5e8c92f4

scala> p.get
res1: Int = 42
```

Note that since the wrapper is a value class, you won't be paying any extra-instantiation price

Comment: You could make `DirectAccessPromise` extend `AnyVal` to save on the implicit class allocation cost: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14929422/should-implicit-classes-always-extend-anyval

Comment: There's a typo in your tl;dr: `p.future === p`

Answer (score 4):

The [DefaultPromise](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/concurrent/impl/Promise.scala) returns *itself* as the future, so you aren't making an extra allocation. Even if you were, the cost of the thread safety is likely much greater.