# How to efficiently select a random element from a Scala immutable HashSet

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have a `scala.collection.immutable.HashSet` that I want to randomly select an element from.

I could solve the problem with an extension method like this:

```
implicit class HashSetExtensions[T](h: HashSet[T]) {
  def nextRandomElement (): Option[T] = {
    val list = h.toList
    list match {
      case null | Nil => None
      case _ => Some (list (Random.nextInt (list.length)))
    }
  }
}
```

...but converting to a list will be slow.  What would be the most efficient solution?

Comment: Is this `mutable.HashSet` or `immutable.HashSet` you are using?

Comment: I suspect using an Iterator on the Set directly, and advancing it a random number of times between 0 and the size of the set may be better than converting to a List, but I don't know what the implementation of size or iterator are on HashSet so I'm not sure.

Comment: actually the solution what I proposed with `Random.shuffle(h).headOption` is completely wrong, it returns always the same result

Answer (score 2):

**WARNING** This answer is for experimental use only. For real project you probably should use your own collection types.

So i did some research in the [HashSet source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.6/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/HashSet.scala#L1) and i think there is little opportunity to someway extract the inner structure of most valuable [`class HashTrieSet`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.6/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/HashSet.scala#L1) without package violation.

I did come up with this code, which is extended [Ben Reich's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29802897/210905):

```
package scala.collection

import scala.collection.immutable.HashSet
import scala.util.Random

package object random {
  implicit class HashSetRandom[T](set: HashSet[T]) {
    def randomElem: Option[T] = set match {
      case trie: HashSet.HashTrieSet[T] => {
        trie.elems(Random.nextInt(trie.elems.length)).randomElem
      }
      case _ => Some(set.size) collect {
        case size if size > 0 => set.iterator.drop(Random.nextInt(size)).next
      }
    }
  }
}
```

file should be created somewhere in the `src/scala/collection/random` folder

note the `scala.collection` package - this thing makes the `elems` part of `HashTrieSet` visible. This is only solution i could think, which could run better than `O(n)`. Current version should have complexity `O(ln(n))` as any of `immutable.HashSet`'s operation s.

Another warning - private structure of `HashSet` is not part of scala's standard library API, so it could change any version making this code erroneous (though it's didn't changed since 2.8)

Comment: Probably over the top, but clever.  You could probably do something similar for mutable `HashSet` as well (might even be able to get that one in constant time if you can expose the inner hash table array).   Also, if we're going over the top anyway, you can probably reconfigure some things here to make your method here tail recursive!

Comment: @BenReich There is no need to provide tail recursion here since it would not be called more than `2*log_32(n)` times. We could try to optimize it to call `Random.nextInt` only one time, since multiple call not only expensive, but also provides non-uniform distribution over leaves of not-perfectly balanced tree.

Answer (score 1):

Since `size` is `O(1)` on `HashSet`, and `iterator` is as lazy as possible, I think this solution would be relatively efficient:

```
implicit class RichHashSet[T](val h: HashSet[T]) extends AnyVal {
    def nextRandom: Option[T] = Some(h.size) collect {
        case size if size > 0 => h.iterator.drop(Random.nextInt(size)).next
    }
}
```

And if you're trying to get every ounce of efficiency you could use `match` here instead of the more concise `Some/collect` idiom used here.

You can look at the [`mutable HashSet`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.5/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/HashSet.scala#L1) implementation to see the `size` method.  The `iterator` method defined there basically just calls `iterator` on [`FlatHashTable`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.5/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/FlatHashTable.scala#L1).  The same basic efficiencies of these methods apply to [`immutable HashSet`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.4/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/HashSet.scala#L1) if that's what you're working with. As a comparison, you can see the `toList` implementation on `HashSet` is all the way up the type hierarchy at [`TraversableOnce`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.5/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableOnce.scala#L1) and uses far more primitive elements which are probably less efficient and (of course) the entire collection must be iterated to generate the `List`. If you *were* going to convert the entire set to a `Traversable` collection, you should use `Array` or `Vector` which have constant-time lookup.

You might also note that there is nothing special about `HashSet` in the above methods, and you could enrich `Set[T]` instead, if you so chose (although there would be no guarantee that this would be as efficient on other `Set` implementations, of course).

As a side note, when implementing enriched classes for extension methods, you should always consider making an implicit, user-defined value class by extending `AnyVal`.  You can read about some of the advantages and limitations in the [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.AnyVal), and on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14931302/1223622).

Comment: `Iterator.drop` would iterate through whole dropped part of set. It's complexity is really O(n)

Comment: Right – I didn't mean to say the whole method was `O(1)`, just that `size` was `O(1)`.  This is still `O(n)`, but with a better average- and worst-case.

Comment: It's definitely better than build new collection but i steel looking it the HashSet.scala to find how to hack-out parts of HashTrieSet to make this O(log(n))

Comment: if you extended `HashSet`, you could expose the inner hash table (which is an `Array`), and then pick a random element in constant time!  Although that's probably unwise.

Comment: Trouble is that we could not expose. That is private to `scala.immutable.collection` not protected. So only thing we could do - define new class inside the `collection` package which is totally crap

Comment: And second issue - we could not force `HashSet` factory and other HashSet subclasses to use our new class  instead of original HashTrieSet